# Quickest way to create PDF with images - full page scans

Tags: windows, windows-8, pdf

I have to perform a task on frequent basis and that is scanning a bunch of pages(all pages with same size) and create a PDF file out of it so that the PDF will appear as close to original pages as possible which means no margins, no cropping.

Now I know a clumsy way to do this. Fire up Word, set correct page size and set margins to zero. Import images(if you import multiple, Word messes up the order) and save as PDF.
Now this is tedious procedure if you have to do it frequently.

Is there any way to do it faster?

I have already seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/393214/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-from-scanned-images-i-have-in-my-folder) question with only one answer useful to me and it was marked off-topic(I don't know why). I am just trying to open up the topic to find the best way for this task.

Comment: What type of device are you using to scan.  Adobe Acrobat has the ability to batch OCR files which auto-rotates and does a bunch of stuff

Comment: If you don't mind good quality, I use an iPhone app called CamScanner (https://itunes.apple.com/ar/app/camscanner-free/id388627783?mt=8). It allows you to take many pictures and then combines them to one PDF.

Comment: The linked question has for a product recommendation your current question while it might require a software suggestion is worded in a way where it's not requesting a product recommendation

Comment: @Ramhound: Its my HP all-in-one. And its not actually OCR. Its my handwritten homework.

Comment: @l19: Thanks but I don't have an iDevice

Comment: Yes I know but Acrobat will attempt to OCR it and straighten up the image by doing so.  Plus some of the document will be text recognized.  My hp supports scanning to PDF or image there is a solution in the other question that should work

Comment: I am stuck on my printers ability to scan a document to a PDF hence why I brought the OCR capability.  What printer do you have exactly?

Comment: HP Photosmart C4580...It can scan to PNG or JPEG and I think PDF as well. But it creates one PDF per page

Answer (score 1):

Just had to scan a number of documents and convert JPEG images to a single PDF file myself. Here is what I did on Windows 10 without having to install any extra software.

Select the images you want to include in the PDF file from Windows Explorer, Right click, choose Print.

[image: Select images to include in the PDF file]

Choose Microsoft Print to PDF as the Printer option. Click Print, specify filename for output PDF file. 
[image: Print Pictures dialog]

**Optional: To change document orientation**

In case your document is in Landscape mode, go to Options (as highlighted in the above screenshot) to change it to Portrait mode.

[image: Print settings dialog]

Go to Printer Properties...

[image: Microsoft Print to PDF Document Properties to change to Portrait mode]

Change to Portrait mode (if required) and click OK.

[image: Generated PDF containing all pages]

Again, in the Print Pictures dialog (see Picture 2), click Print. Specify output filename. This will create a PDF file with multiple pages.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

[Download PrimoPDF](http://filehippo.com/download_primopdf). Select your images and right click on them and choose "print".

[image]

Chose PrimoPDF as printer and click on print.

[image]

Click on "create PDF" and save the file.

[image]

Comment: PrimoPDF appears to be just a PDF printer driver.  Wouldn't this approach create a separate PDF for each image?  Can you clarify how to create a single PDF this way?  Thanks.

Comment: answer's been edited

Comment: That creates a single PDF?  So PrimoPDF acts more like an application than a simple PDF printer driver?

Comment: Yes, it creates a single file

Answer (score -1):

Try [WinScan2PDF](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/WinScan2PDF). It's a freeware that has very simple UI and can scan multiple pages into single pdf file.

Comment: The question asks how to do it, so just naming a tool is more of a helpful hint (comment), than an answer (which is likely why your answer got downvoted).  The other answer is a good example of how to recommend software.  Read this thread for guidance: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.

Comment: FYI: This is probably not spam as the username and the name on the impressum page of the linked site do not match.